# Как получить подпись файла, полученного Telegram ботом на Python?

Tags: python, файлы, telegram-bot, telebot

боту отправляется файл, скачивается. Скачивается функцией

```
def handle_docs_photo(message):
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

    src = 'files/' + file_info.file_path
    with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)

    bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуй, я сохраню это")
```

Как получить "подпись" к файлу (текст, который пишется при прикреплении файла в Telegram).
В telegram.File не нашел такой функции

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ message. За подпись отвечает message.caption

например
'bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.caption)'
отправляет подпись в чат